# "The file is not synchronized" when trying auomated refactor in jUnit

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm writing a plugin that refactors the whole code base of a project based on a rule. Since I would like to test it automaticly, I am writing some test with jUnit.

Now, for each test I need to setup a workspace, create a test project, add some files and then apply the refactoring on them. This works perfectly fine if I have exactly one test, but as soon as I write a second test method, I get a  `Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 274] The file is not synchronized with the local file system.`

I assume that the problem has to do with a file still beeing held in memory, but not deleted correctly. I tried various ways of deleting and refreshing the projects, but none of them work perfectly (though the contents get deleted on the filesystem).

Does anybody have a idea how to solve this issue?

Setup-Method:

```
@Before
public void setup() {

    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(); 

    iProject = root.getProject("MyProject");
    try {
        iProject.create(null);
        iProject.open(null);

        IProjectDescription description = iProject.getDescription();
        description.setNatureIds(new String[] { JavaCore.NATURE_ID });
        iProject.setDescription(description, null);

        iJavaProject = JavaCore.create(iProject);

        IFolder binFolder = iProject.getFolder("bin");
        binFolder.create(true, true, null);
        iJavaProject.setOutputLocation(binFolder.getFullPath(), null);

        sourceFolder = iProject.getFolder("src");
        sourceFolder.create(true, true, null);

        IClasspathEntry[] buildPath = {
                JavaCore.newSourceEntry(iProject.getFullPath()
                        .append("src")),
                JavaRuntime.getDefaultJREContainerEntry() };

        iJavaProject.setRawClasspath(buildPath, iProject.getFullPath()
                .append("bin"), null);
        // create package
        iPackage = iJavaProject.getPackageFragmentRoot(sourceFolder)
                .createPackageFragment(PACKAGE_NAME, false, null);

        //create the java class
       ICompilationUnit iUnitUtilityClass = iPackage.createCompilationUnit("Bars.java", existingUtilityClass, false, null);
        ....
        //more files
```

The Clean-up method:

```
@After
public void cleanup() throws CoreException, InterruptedException {
    //various ways of deleting the project          
    iProject.delete(true, true, null);

    iProject.delete(IResource.FORCE | IResource.ALWAYS_DELETE_PROJECT_CONTENT | IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new NullProgressMonitor());

    ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().delete(new IResource[] {iProject.getProject()}, true, null);
    iProject = null;

    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
            root.delete(true, true, null);      
}
```

Test-Method:
        ....

```
    ICompilationUnit iUnit = iPackage.createCompilationUnit("Bar.java",
            fileName, false, null);


    MoveUtilityMethodsToUtilityClassHandler handler= new  MoveUtilityMethodsToUtilityClassHandler();
    iUnit.save(null, true);
    Result result = handler.handle(iUnit); //<--- here, the exception is thrown
    ....
```

The Exception:

```
Java Model Exception: Core Exception [code 274] The file is not synchronized with the local file system.
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BatchOperation.executeOperation(BatchOperation.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.run(JavaCore.java:5332)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.changes.DynamicValidationStateChange.perform(DynamicValidationStateChange.java:116)
at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
at ch.ergon.advancedrefactoring.handlers.MoveUtilityMethodsToUtilityClassVisitor.moveTo(MoveUtilityMethodsToUtilityClassVisitor.java:293)
at ch.ergon.advancedrefactoring.handlers.MoveUtilityMethodsToUtilityClassVisitor.visit(MoveUtilityMethodsToUtilityClassVisitor.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration.accept0(MethodDeclaration.java:489)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration.accept0(TypeDeclaration.java:484)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.acceptChildren(ASTNode.java:2585)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit.accept0(CompilationUnit.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode.accept(ASTNode.java:2514)
at ch.ergon.advancedrefactoring.handlers.MoveUtilityMethodsToUtilityClassHandler.handle(MoveUtilityMethodsToUtilityClassHandler.java:45)
at ch.ergon.advancedrefactoring.UtilityRefactorTest.testMoveToExistingUtiliyClass(UtilityRefactorTest.java:197)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: How are you creating the files and folders? This is what is causing the issue.

Comment: How come? I added the source code for the creating of folders, files and packages, I thought it doesn't matter.

Comment: Because if you don't use the Eclipse methods for creating files and folders you get the 'not synchronized' message.

Comment: so which are the eclipse methods for creating files and folders? I thought the iProject.getFolder("src").createFolder() is the eclipse way to do it...

Comment: Yes what you have show looks OK. Try the `refreshLocal` call

Comment: The refreshLocal call didn't make any difference...

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that someone changed a file without telling Eclipse. So you need to look for code which uses the normal Java API to modify files or something which runs outside of your test or Eclipse and which changes files (like the file indexer on Windows).

You can also try to force a refresh using `refreshLocal()` of [IResource](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fresources%2FIResource.html).

Comment: I used the refreshLocal on iProject in different spots in the code with different flags, none of them worked so far...

Comment: Set a breakpoint and try to find out which file is out of sync.

Comment: It is the file Bar.java

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem (well, not really) with a dirty workaround.

Since the project does not get deleted cleanly, I just use a different name for each project I create.

So, in the first test, the project is named "Project0", in the second test "Project1", and so on. This works.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    projectName = "Project" + projectCount++;
    System.out.println("Create Project " + projectName);
    IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot(); 

    iProject = root.getProject(projectName);
    try {
        iProject.create(null);
    .....
```

Not my favourite solution, but it works... And Eclipse cleans the workspace after the tests anyway.

Comment: Can you try to wait for all background jobs to finish before you start the next test? Eclipse does a whole lot of work in the background; cleaning up after deleting a project is one of it.